# Proportional distribution

Tags: excel, vba, distribution

Can you please help me to understand how to distribute the amount using coefficient and quantity for every part using some formula or VBA macro?
The table is really large to do it manually. 
[Please find excel table extract sample.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AoMHe_jxCdkDj_9TutQTpp2bjIVEGg) 
"Amount to be distributed" column corresponds to the "Key" and each cell is duplicated, so e.g. cells E2-E4 should not be summarized. The first line of each duplication occurence in the "Amount to be distributed" column should be distributed using "Coefficient" and "Quantity".
E.g. I want 733134.89/(110+60+90) then distribute the given proportionally to D2, D3, D4

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Do you want `733134.89` divided by 3 and `1183474.22` divided by 7? You're not very clear.

Comment: I want 733134.89/(110+60+90) then distribute the given proportionally to D2, D3, D4.

Comment: What does 'distribute the given proportionally' mean? Give me an end result. After the formula is calculated should all three equal `733134.89`? FYI - people on here will not typically answer a question apart from seeing what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your data at present (which should be shown in OP and not merely via a link or an image):

[image: SO39204257 first example]

and assuming ColumnF shows what you are trying to achieve, a PivotTable with VALUES of Amount to be distributed proportionally as Max of, Count of and Sum of with the last Shown as % of Grand Total:

[image: SO39204257 second example]

would provide values for a formula in L2 and copied down to suit of:

```
=K2/J2
```

which could be the basis for a lookup table for a formula in F2 and copied down to suit of:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,H:L,5,0)
```